# I just want the rows where a change in county names occurs

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to find the route,milepoint and county name only for the locations where the change in county occurs along the highway route. I am very new to SQL so the query I have used is very simple:

```
select NRLG_ROUTE,NRLG_MILEPOINT,NRLG_COUNTY
from TIS.TIS_NEW_ROADLOG t
order by 1
```

So what im trying to do is find the rows where NRLG_COUNTY only occurs where NRLG_ROUTES changes from one county to another. I just dont want the rows of data within or through each county,just at the boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know when the "next" county is different from the "current" county, based on the `milepoint`.  This suggests using `lead()`:

```
select rl.*
from (select rl.nrlg_route, rl.nrlg_milepoint, rl.nrlg_county,
             lead(rl.nrlg_county) over (partition by rl.nrlg_route
                                        order by rl.nrlg_milepoint) as next_county
      from tis.tis_new_roadlog rl
     ) rl
where county <> next_country;
```

Comment: That seems to done the trick. I'll look at it a little closer. Thank you very much. Soon I should be able to verify this as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you only apply conditions to one row (each row), not to consecutive rows. That is, unless you use analytical functions with `over`.

So you need to join the table with itself shifted by one row in the desired ordering. Here's an example for you (tested on SQLite):

```
# prepare some data
create table route(ordinal int not null primary key, road varchar(10));
insert into route values(1, "foo");
insert into route values (2, "foo");
insert into route values (3, "bar");
insert into route values (4, "bar");
insert into route values (5, "baz");

# the query
select 
  r1.ordinal, r1.road as "from", r2.road as "to"
from 
  route r1, route r2  # same table under different aliases
where 
  r1.ordinal = r2.ordinal - 1 and # r2 record goes right after r1
  r1.road != r2.road # the road has changed
;
```

It expectedly gives:

```
    from  to
2 | foo | bar
4 | bar | baz
```

It will be a bit trickier that that if your ordinals (`NRLG_ROUTE`) have holes, though.